# Locking the contents of data.table tables

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to make a data.table static (i.e. non-updatable)? Using the lockBinding() function prevents the variable being re-assigned, however, the columns of the data table can still be edited. Example:

```
> dt = data.table( x = 1:5 )
> lockBinding( "dt", env = environment() )
> dt = 1
Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'dt'
> dt[ , x := 1 ]
> dt[ , x ]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

I guess it is related to how data tables are referenced, however, it would be useful to be able to lock the contents of the data table as well. (I often have shared reference tables that I don't want to update by accident.)

Comment: @dww that is one advantage, but data.table has many other advantages over data.frame. For example, since these are reference tables they will often be joined to other data.tables.

Comment: conversation has been moved to Github, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2918

Answer (score 4):

This is kinda tricky. One way to do it is to hijack the `[` function to disallow the use of `:=` on the object. If we want to bind a data.table, we can add a class to it, like so:

```
boundDT <- function(dt){
  class(dt) <- c("bound.data.table", class(dt))
  dt
}
```

Result:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table( x = 1:5 )
bound <- boundDT(dt)
class(bound)
[1] "bound.data.table" "data.table"       "data.frame"
```

If we then create a new indexing function to work on the `bound.data.table` class, we can do our thing:

```
`[.bound.data.table` <- function(dt, ...){
  if(any(unlist(sapply(match.call()[-(1:2)], function(x) if(length(x) > 1)as.character(x[1]) == ":=")))){
    stop("Can't use `:=` on this object.")
  }
  class(dt) <- class(dt)[-1]
  dt[...]
}
```

This checks whether the function `:=` is used in the call and throws an error if it does. Else it removes the bound class on the internal copy of the data.table, and calls the regular `[` function.

```
bound[, x := 1]
 Error in `[.bound.data.table`(bound, , `:=`(x, 1)) : 
  Can't use `:=` on this object. 
bound[, x]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

This is ugly, but it seems to work.

One caveat:

When using `:=` in a join, this does not work if the bound table is not the base table:

```
dt = data.table( x = 1:5 , y = 5:1)
bound <- boundDT(dt)
dt[bound, y := 1, on = .(x = x)]
bound
   x y
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
4: 4 1
5: 5 1
```

However:

```
bound[dt, y := 1, on = .(x = x)]
 Error in `[.bound.data.table`(bound, dt, `:=`(y, 1), on = .(x = x)) : 
  Can't use `:=` on this object.
```

## Preventing the use of `set*`

With most issues around the `:=` operator out of the way, we can focus on preventing the use of `set*` on our object.

When the bound data.table is used, we can check the call-stack to see if there are any `set*` functions, before providing the data.table.

```
bindDT <- function(dt){
  bound <- boundDT(dt)
  function(){
    calls <- sys.calls()
    forbidden <- c("set", "set2key", "set2keyv", "setattr", "setcolorder", "setdiff", "setDT", 
                   "setDTthreads", "setequal", "setindex", "setindexv", "setkey", "setkeyv", 
                   "setnames", "setNumericRounding", "setorder", "setorderv")
    matches <- unlist(lapply(calls, function(x) as.character(x)[1] %in% forbidden))
    if(any(matches)){
      stop(paste0("Can't use function ", calls[[which(matches)[1]]][1], " on bound data.table."))
    }

    bound
  }
}
```

This function binds the data.table like before, but instead of returning this, it returns a function. This function, when called checks the callstack for `set*` functions and throws an error if it finds any. I got this list from the data.table help-page, so this should be complete.

You can use active binding to avoid having to call the data.table as a function for each use, using `pryr`:

```
library(data.table)
library(pryr)

dt = data.table( x = 1:5 , y = 5:1)
bound %<a-% (bindDT(dt))()

setkey(bound, x)
Error in (bindDT(dt))() : Can't use function setkey on bound data.table.
```

Comment: Good progress but it only prevents certain types of updates. For example, setnames() will change the original. Maybe it is possible to enumerate all the possible actions to block, however, would be rather hacky and would bound to break on updates to data.table.

Comment: @Rob ah yes, the `set*` wouldn't be blockable through this. I don't think there is much to be done eventually. Maybe you should file a feature-request on their github?

Comment: thanks, looks like there is an issue already on Githhub for this. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1086

Comment: @Rob I guess some additional safeguards could be added, partially by combining this with jogo's suggestions. I'll give it another go tomorrow.

Comment: @Rob I added a mechanism for preventing `set*` calls

Answer (score 1):

You can put the data.table in a function:

```
library("data.table")
dt = function() data.table( x = 1:5 )
dt() = 1 ### error
dt()[ , x := 1 ]
dt()[ , x ]
# > dt()[ , x ]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Here is a variant to not generate the data.table every time:

```
library("data.table")
dt0 = data.table( x = 1:5 )
dt <- function() copy(dt0)
dt() = 1
dt()[ , x := 1 ]
dt()[ , x ]
```

I am not very happy with my solution: it copies the data.table every time one wants to use it.  Every time you want to use the *unchanged* data.table you have to do it by calling the function `dt()`

Comment: Wouldn't this be really impractical when you're trying to lock large data.tables? Each call recreates the entire table.

Comment: I agree with JAD, unfortunately these tables are often large and I don't want to be creating multiple copies.

Comment: @JAD I will present a work around to overcome the repeated generation of the data.table.

Comment: Wouldn't this still create a complete copy every time `dt` is called?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, look at the following example:               
    > dt0 = data.table( x = 1:5 )
    > dt <- function() dt0
    > dt1 = dt()
    > dt1[,x:=1]
   > dt()[,x]
   [1] 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, it creates a copy. But it is not *generating* the data.table. For your other question I don't know; in the question is *I don't want to update by accident*.

Comment: @Rob By doing that you will have the same problem with `dt1` as in your question with `dt`. Using my answer: every time you want to use the *unchanged* data.table you have to do it calling the function `dt()`

Comment: @jogo that is a bit better, albeit with large tables it might still be a big overhead. I can't think of anything better though, so I guess this is the best thing.

Comment: @jogo unfortunately the copying is the expensive bit I want to avoid. My current work around is similar to yours (I store the calculated data on a non-exposed variable in a package and then my functions return a copy() of that)

Answer (score 1):

```
attr(dt, ".data.table.locked") = TRUE
```

will lock most data.table operations.  A few operations (`setnames`) may still sneak past though.  Beware, however, that this is an undocumented internal feature of data.table intended for other purposes. As a result, the error messages you receive if you try to alter a locked table will look strange and confusing. And there are no guarantees about how it will perform in later versions of the package.

If you do decide to go this route, you should also use `lockBinding` afterwards to lock base R type operations too.

Comment: Looks like this is either a half-implemented data.table solution or .data.table.locked is used for something else in .data.table. There are a few open issues around this on Github and I've exchange mails with Matt Dowle about this. We'll start a conversation up on Github and I will post a link once it is going.

Comment: @Rob I've found that dt[,str(.SD)]  shows  attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>  and 
 attr(*, ".data.table.locked")= logi TRUE   Maybe it's used to prevent the user from modifying .SD attributes.