# Protecting fields in R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm doing some work with data frames in R. I'm wondering if there is a way of setting some/all fields in a data frame to be "read only" (or similar) - to prevent accidental changing/deletion? Would be a very useful feature for me!

(Generally with data frames I'll want to read the fields, and sometimes to add new fields, but I won't want to modify fields that are already present)

I've done a little Googling on the topic but it wasn't much help.

Thanks
Alan

Comment: Some related discussion from a decade ago - http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-make-read-only-data-frames-td844759.html

Comment: Also somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583429/locking-the-contents-of-data-table-tables/50615480#50615480

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it's not possible yet, but I think it could be a useful feature.

And I think I can make something that does that.

A new class, e.g. `protected.data.frame`, could be similar to `data.frame`, except all modifying calls first check if modification is allowed.
I think it will be hard to make it absolutely secure, but it could work against accidental modifcation.

This weekend I have some spare time, I'll let you know if I've made something useful.

Comment: That would be incredibly useful, if you can find the time. Thank you very much!